# Problem retrieving FakeDb DbLinkField attributes

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

```
db.Add(new DbTemplate("t1", t1_TemplateId));
db.Add(new DbTemplate("T", T_TemplateId)
        {
            BaseIDs = new[] { t1_TemplateId}
        });

db.Add(new DbItem("root")
{
    new DbItem("child1")
    {
        new DbItem("siteRoot")
        {
            new DbItem("Home")
            {
                new DbItem("Article")
            },
            new DbItem("Data")
            {
                new DbItem("theItem", ID.NewID, T_TemplateId)
                {
                    new DbLinkField("theField")
                    {
                        Anchor = "anchor",
                        Class = "class",
                        LinkType = "linktype",
                        QueryString = "querystring",
                        Target = "target",
                        TargetID = targetid,
                        Text = "text",
                        Title = "title",
                        Url = "url",
                    },
                    new DbLinkField("otherfield")
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

And then I try to get the values:

```
Item theItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/root/child1/siteRoot/Data/theItem");
LinkField theField = theItem.Fields["theField"];
```

All attributes defined are missing...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version FakeDb/Sitecore do you use?

Comment: Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release, Sitecore.FakeDb 1.3.1

Comment: Don't you have the same issue when you are using real Sitecore items?

Comment: When I have an item and I get a LinkField is working perfectly. But I want to mock that item and there is where the problem appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally found my mistake. Since I am using DbTemplates, the DbLinkField needs to be added to the template first.

```
db.Add(new DbTemplate("t1", t1_TemplateId)){
    new DbLinkfield("theField")
});
db.Add(new DbTemplate("T", T_TemplateId)
{
    BaseIDs = new[] { t1_TemplateId}
});

db.Add(new DbItem("root")
{
    new DbItem("child1")
    {
        new DbItem("siteRoot")
        {
            new DbItem("Home")
            {
                new DbItem("Article")
            },
            new DbItem("Data")
            {
                new DbItem("theItem", ID.NewID, T_TemplateId)
                {
                    new DbLinkField("theField")
                    {
                        Anchor = "anchor",
                        Class = "class",
                        LinkType = "linktype",
                        QueryString = "querystring",
                        Target = "target",
                        TargetID = targetid,
                        Text = "text",
                        Title = "title",
                        Url = "url",
                    },
                    new DbLinkField("otherfield")
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code is working, maybe the Db context is missing in your code?

```
using (var db = new Db
{
    new DbItem("theItem", ID.NewID)
    {
        new DbLinkField("theField")
        {
            Anchor = "anchor",
            Class = "class",
            LinkType = "linktype",
            QueryString = "querystring",
            Target = "target",
            TargetID = ID.NewID,
            Text = "text",
            Title = "title",
            Url = "url",
        }
    }
})
{
    var item = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/theItem");
    LinkField field = item.Fields["theField"];
}
```

Comment: This is weird. This code isolated is working good for me, but if the item structure is more complex then is not working anymore...

Comment: Hm, let's post the the more complex structure into your question.

Comment: I've edited the question with the exact structure

Answer (score 0):

May sound like a silly question, but have you added your item to the fake db? The code below is working fine on my end:

```
var item = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("theItem", ID.NewID, ID.NewID);
var field = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbLinkField("theField")
{
    Anchor = "anchor",
    Class = "class",
    LinkType = "linktype",
    QueryString = "querystring",
    Target = "target",
    TargetID = ID.NewID,
    Text = "text",
    Title = "title",
    Url = "url",
};

item.Add(field);

var db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db("web");
db.Add(item);

var fakeItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/theItem");
LinkField theField = fakeItem.Fields["theField"];
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't post that part but it is added to the Db. The only problem is with this kind of field. Items, templates, inheritance... that is working good.